# What does the c operator *y=&x[] actually mean?

Tags: c, operators

```
uint16_t x[] = {1,2,4,8};
uint16_t *y = &x[1];
y+=2;
```

So the output is 8 and I wanted to know why? In my opinion this should equal to 4, because &x[1] should be 2 and adding 2 should equal 4. What am I missing?

Comment: Output? Post more code, please

Comment: PS: y += 2; just moves the pointer

Comment: It's 3 separate operators and a type specifier.

Comment: This is called pointer arithmetic, it'll become clear once you read about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's your array:

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3]
   +---+---+---+---+
x= | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+
```

`y = &x[1]` is a pointer to `x[1]`, the second element:

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3]
   +---+---+---+---+
x= | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+
         ^
         |
         y
```

`y += 2` moves `y` two steps to the right:

```
    [0] [1] [2] [3]
   +---+---+---+---+
x= | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 |
   +---+---+---+---+
                 ^
                 |
                 y
```

and now `*y` is 8

Answer (score 3):

```
uint16_t *y = &x[1];
```

It means the pointer `y` will hold the address of the "`x[1]`" array element.

```
y+=2;
```

Then, the pointer moves two positions after `x[1]`, So it holds the address of the "`x[3]`" array element.

Comment: @StoryTeller I Stand corrected. I think then the implementation specific part is just whether they are numbers or something else.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - Indeed

Answer (score 1):

Well,

This line says: 
`uint16_t *y = &x[1];`

- `y` is a pointer to the same memory location where `x[1]` is stored. 
  `x[1]` has memory location equal to `address_of(x) + 1*sizeof(uint16_t)`

Then `y+=2` comes into play:

- This tells the compiler: I want `y` to point two memory location ahead of the currently pointed by `y`. How the compiler knows what to to? It knows the type of `y` and can just jump ahead two memory locations the same way as it did for the `[]`.

`y+=2 => y + 2*sizeof(uint16_t) = x + 1*sizeof(uint16_t) + 2*sizeof(uint16_t) = x + 3*sizeof(uint16_t) = x[3]`.

`y` points now two locations ahead. Since it was pointing to  `x[1]`, now points to `x[3]`.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that `x[1]` is not what holds the value 1, `x[1]` is the second element, so `x[1] == 2`. In other words:

```
&x[1] == x + 1
```

and so

```
*y = x + 1
```

2 indices further from that is `*(x + 3)`, aka `x[3]` or `8`.

Comment: RIght, but the original snippet said y + 2,  hence my comment/question.

Comment: `*y = x + 1` is a bit misleading.

Comment: not understanding that `*y = &x[1]` and `*y = x + 1` are the same is the whole reason this question was asked

Answer (score -1):

The pointer y value is the address of x[1] and in the next step, the value of y is incremented by 2.

Say, that the value of y is 1000 (The address of x[1]). After incremented by 2, the value would be 1002.

So when you print the output would be 8, which is the value at x[3] or x[1+2]